# ReOrdering ADF table columns at Arabic locale

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

i created a new sample ADF application with only a table, and configured locale to be 'ar'.
when i try to reorder columns , table got freeze and i get error as below :

[image]

the error only appears while locale is 'ar', if i set locale to 'en' it works well

any ideas ?

thanks

Update : i am using "Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.3.0"

Comment: You may need to add the ADF version you are using. And if it's the last version this could be a framework bug to open an SR on

Comment: @Cedric i am using "Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.3.0" - "Build JDEVADF_12.2.1.PATCHSETS_GENERIC_170820.0914.S"

Comment: So try installing 12.2.1.4 and reproduce. If it's the same error you may need to open a bug